# display argparse help within pydoc

Tags: python, argparse, pydoc

I have seen questions about displaying pydoc in the output of argparse's help, but I haven't seen anything about the reverse, which to me, seems more useful.

Is there any way to have pydoc automagically render the synopsis and per-item help description for a Python program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the help string with the `format_help()` method. You could use that to add to your script's doc string. One simple example:

```
"""
This is my script.
"""

import argparse

def _make_parser():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument("foo", help="Specify foo")
    x = p.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    x.add_argument('--uid')
    x.add_argument('--username')
    return p

_p = _make_parser()

__doc__ += _p.format_help()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = _p.parse_args()
```

Comment: I wondered if something like this would work, but I can't seem to get it to work.  For one thing, if I have the argparse stuff defined in main(), I just don't see anything extra in the pydoc, and if I define it in the main scope (in a test program), I get an error when I run `pydoc test_docs.py`, since not all required arguments are present when pydoc is being run:  `jazz% pydoc ./test_docs.py 
usage: pydoc [-h] [--file FILE] (--uid | --username) ...
pydoc: error: one of the arguments --uid --username is required
problem in ./test_docs.py - <type 'exceptions.SystemExit'>: 2`

Comment: You'll have to make sure that the parser object gets defined at import time, although you can still keep the call to `parse_args` in a `main` function.

Comment: Even with everything at global scope, I still get the error above. That is, it's trying to parse the arguments as if the program's being executed, rather than just building the usage for it.

Comment: It sounds like `parse_args()` is being called when the module is imported. Make sure it is only executed when run as a script.